# Eclipse CDT: Type std::string could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have been searching for a solution to this problem for quite some time, and cannot find something that actually works. I have tried all of the solutions I could find in other questions on stackoverflow (and elsewhere), but none seem to work.

Before I begin, I am running Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse 3.7.2, and I have g++ 4.6.3 installed.

When I try to use any of the std includes, I get an error saying that the type could not be resolved. For example, here is a bit of my code:

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H_
#define UTILITY_H_

#include <string.h>

class Utility {
public:
    static std::string test() // <- Error at this line
    {
        return "";
    }
};


#endif /* UTILITY_H_ */
```

At the indicated line, I get an error that says `Type 'std::string' could not be resolved`. Note that the include statement is resolved just fine, but the type from that included file was not. I get the same error for `#include <sstream>`, and presumably anything else that I haven't written myself.

I have already tried:

- Making sure I have the proper toolchain and include paths, as well as switching to another toolchain, applying the change, then re-applying the old toolchain.
- Restarting both eclipse and my computer multiple times.
- `#include <string>` and `#include <string.h>`, neither of which work. I have, however, been able to expand my includes folders to find the file where I would expect it to be.

Below is a picture of what I'm seeing, if that helps more:

[image]

Edit: Alright, I get it, `#include <string.h>` isn't what I actually want, but as I said above, `#include <string>` does not produce new results.

**EDIT: I have apparently fixed the problem. How I do not know, but see my answer**

Comment: What folders do you have in include path?

Comment: First, the correct include is `<string>`, not `<string.h>`, so scrub the `<string.h>` idea.

Comment: How about possibly, Eclipse and/or the plug-in has a bug?  Eclipse is not a compiler.

Comment: @AndreyDerevyanko the folders are shown in the picture, unless you're talking about something else. From the other stuff that I've read and seen while trying to solve this, those seem to be the correct include folders

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works or what I could have done, but I just ran the project to see what would happen. Seems to have resolved the errors, as they disappeared once I ran it. Maybe the error messages are a bit buggy and were left over from when the include initially couldn't be resolved.

Comment: Lucky you are, still no solution works for me. In addition to your attempts, I have also rebuid the project index.

Comment: Finally, migrating to Eclipse Neon solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has different build configurations (Debug/Release). The indexer uses Debug configuration by default (at least in my case). Change it: 
Project | Properties | C/C++ General | Indexer | Build configuration for the indexer | Release | [Apply] | [OK]. 
Maybe you have to start indexing: 
Project | C/C++ Index | Rebuild

N.B.: Of course, all the paths have to be set correctly for Release configuration as proposed in many other answers to this topic. But without this change all other changes are useless.